# Create scala.xml.Elem with specific childs

Tags: scala

I'd like to create a new scala.xml.Elem based on a node with a specific list of childs.
This would be the return case in a recursive replace function.

```
val childs: Seq[Node] = update(node.child)
new Elem(node.prefix, node.label, node.attributes, node.scope, true, childs)
```

This construct gives compiler error:

```
Error:(50, 11) overloaded method constructor Elem with alternatives:
  (prefix: String,label: String,attributes: scala.xml.MetaData,scope:  scala.xml.NamespaceBinding,child: scala.xml.Node*)scala.xml.Elem <and>
  (prefix: String,label: String,attributes1: scala.xml.MetaData,scope:  scala.xml.NamespaceBinding,minimizeEmpty: Boolean,child: scala.xml.Node*)scala.xml.Elem
  cannot be applied to (String, String, scala.xml.MetaData, scala.xml.NamespaceBinding, Boolean, Seq[scala.xml.Node])
      new Elem(node.prefix, node.label, node.attributes, node.scope, true, childs)
      ^
```

The problem is related to vararg handling, and I can't understand why I have this error. Any idea?

**Update**
I was able to get through the problem with the following ugly construct:

```
val childs: Seq[Node] = update(node.child)
Elem(node.prefix, node.label, node.attributes, node.scope, true)
  .copy(node.prefix, node.label, node.attributes, node.scope, true, childs)
```

First create the elem without childs, then copy and add the childs. The copy method definition is without varargs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your `scope` and `minimizeEmpty` arguments in the wrong order.

Try calling it like this (note I'm using the companion object too, saves a few characters):

```
Elem(node.prefix, node.label, node.attributes, node.scope, true,  childs)
```

**Update** after the question was updated - ah now I see your problem - `childs` is a `Seq[Node]` but the `Elem` constructor method(s) expect a `Node*`; so you can use:

```
Elem( node.prefix, node.label, node.attributes, node.scope, true,  childs:_* )
```

Comment: UUUps, from 1000 trials the wrong combination was posted. Unfortunately  the correct order also doesn't work.
I edit the original post to fix the "typo".
Thank you anyway the answer.